# PDO, feeding a variable to a Select statement (not where = but directly in statement)

Tags: variables, pdo

I would like to pass a variable directly into the select statement to identify the table, so the code recognizes `SELECT * FROM us_total_Y`. Is this possible with PDO? I have googled around and looked through three books but don't see an example.  Would anyone know? Thank you in advance.

```
  $loc = 'us';
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM :loc _total_Y');
  $stmt->execute(array('loc' => $loc));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the query in a variable like so

```
  $loc = 'us';
  $locquery = 'SELECT * FROM '.$loc.'_total_Y';
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($locquery);
  $stmt->execute();
```